# jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

I'm having jQuery take some textarea content and insert it into an li.

I want it to visually retain the line breaks.

There must be a really simple way to do this...

Comment: XSS note:If you're doing this it sounds like you're directly mixing user input and <br/>'s, which means you're either displaying newlines or <br/s>, and thus *may* be open to XSS attack, that is if your input is coming from any other user on the site.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

> **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';    
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}
```

> - http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. Odd how this isn't an official function of jQuery.

Comment: cause jQuery is not meant to replace native javascript function like replace, it is focused on CSS selector chaining and easy access! maybe in future version;-)

Comment: Awesome.  Helped me get past the problem with IE7 not supporting white-space: pre-wrap

Comment: Wouldn't that regex mean if a line ends with ">" it wouldn't add the BR? I know in my HTML I use &gt; but user generated content doesn't work so well with that...

Comment: @DaveStein no I have tried this with both '>' and '&gt;' and both times the line breaks are added. I think this function code is basically perfect :)

Comment: Neat! But what's with the `(str+'').replace()`?? why not just `str.replace()`?

Comment: @neokio: to be sure str is a string?

Comment: Anybody else getting double <br>'s with this function? Seems like a similar issue to the php version, but I can't seem to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275006/double-line-breaks-with-pre-tag-and-nl2br

Comment: It was not removing line breaks completely from my code instead it was always leaving behind line breaks and adding `<br/>` i fixed it by removing the `$1` and `$2` from return statement like this: 

 `return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g,  breakTag)`

Answer (score 97):

you can simply do:

```
textAreaContent=textAreaContent.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

Comment: Cheers, this kind of worked, except it would treat multiple line breaks as a single line break.

Comment: I've updated it and now it uses a regexp so if you want to treat multiple line breaks as a single br change the regexp with: /\n+/g

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully someone will find your answer useful, but the function below works as well.  

I feel kind of bad that you're making more effort, but a function is more desirable.

Comment: if you get the error "x.replace is not a function" then use x.toString().replace

Answer (score 40):

In the spirit of changing the *rendering* instead of changing the *content*, the following CSS **makes each newline behave like a `<br>`**:

```
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-line;
```

Why two rules: `pre-line` only affects newlines (thanks for the clue, @KevinPauli). IE6-7 and other old browsers fall back to the more extreme `pre` which also includes `nowrap` and renders multiple spaces. Details on these and other settings (`pre-wrap`) at [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) (thanks @Sablefoste).

While I'm generally averse to the S.O. predilection for [second-guessing the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/209317) rather than answering it, in this case replacing newlines with `<br>` markup may increase vulnerability to **injection attack** with unwashed user input.  You're crossing a bright red line whenever you find yourself changing `.text()` calls to `.html()` which the literal question implies would have to be done.  (Thanks @AlexS for highlighting this point.)  Even if you rule out a security risk at the time, future changes could unwittingly introduce it.  Instead, this CSS allows you to get hard line breaks without markup using the safer `.text()`.

Comment: Depending upon the case, this is the simplest solution, and really answers the question best.  You might also consider any of the the other `white-space:` options, such as `pre-wrap`.  See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: This is really the best answer - string replacement solutions would mean the need to use `.html()` to set the content, which in turn would allow the user to insert arbitrary HTML unless you filter that out in advance.

Comment: Good point about `.html()` danger @AlexS, tried to incorporate.

Answer (score 30):

Put this in your code (preferably in a general js functions library):

```
String.prototype.nl2br = function()
{
    return this.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
}
```

Usage:

```
var myString = "test\ntest2";

myString.nl2br();
```

creating a string prototype function allows you to use this on any string.

Answer (score 3):

Solution

Use this code

```
jQuery.nl2br = function(varTest){
  return varTest.replace(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "<br>");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript function considers whether to use insert or replace to handle the swap.

(Insert or replace HTML line breaks)

```
/**
 * This function is same as PHP's nl2br() with default parameters.
 *
 * @param {string} str Input text
 * @param {boolean} replaceMode Use replace instead of insert
 * @param {boolean} isXhtml Use XHTML 
 * @return {string} Filtered text
 */
function nl2br (str, replaceMode, isXhtml) {

  var breakTag = (isXhtml) ? '<br />' : '<br>';
  var replaceStr = (replaceMode) ? '$1'+ breakTag : '$1'+ breakTag +'$2';
  return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, replaceStr);
}
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgrw3hj1/7/)

> [JavaScript nl2br & br2nl functions](https://gist.github.com/yidas/41cc9272d3dff50f3c9560fb05e7255e)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little jQuery extension for this:

```
$.fn.nl2brText = function (sText) {
    var bReturnValue = 'undefined' == typeof sText;
    if(bReturnValue) {
        sText = $('<pre>').html(this.html().replace(/<br[^>]*>/i, '\n')).text();
    }
    var aElms = [];
    sText.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).forEach(function(sSubstring) {
        if(aElms.length) {
            aElms.push(document.createElement('br'));
        }
        aElms.push(document.createTextNode(sSubstring));
    });
    var $aElms = $(aElms);
    if(bReturnValue) {
        return $aElms;
    }
    return this.empty().append($aElms);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

to improve @Luca Filosofi's accepted answer,

if needed, changing the beginning clause of this regex to be `/([^>[\s]?\r\n]?)` will also ingore the cases where the newline comes after a tag AND some whitespace, instead of just a tag immediately followed by a newline

Answer (score 0):

Another way to insert text from a textarea in the DOM keeping the line breaks is to use the [Node.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property that represents the *rendered* text content of a node and its descendants.

*As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied to the clipboard.*

The property became standard in 2016 and is well supported by modern browsers. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText): 97% global coverage when I posted this answer.