# nl2br() equivalent in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

Currently I add `<BR>` for each `evt.which == 13`. Is there a `nl2br()` for JavaScript, so I can do away with this `evt.which == 13`?

**How different is this from php.js**

```
$('#TextArea').keypress(function(evt) {

    if (evt.which == 13) {

        var range           = $('#TextArea').getSelection();
        var image_selection = range.text;

        $('#TextArea').replaceSelection('<BR>');
        $('#TextArea1').html($('#TextArea').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: white-space: pre-line;

Comment: white-spac:pre-line; only helps to render. If you export the same value to rtf later on, it gets dropped.

Comment: This question could be missleading as it mixes two different problems: `nl2br` and `evt.which == 13`. Really `keypress` and `evt.which == 13` (wich is the event code for `Enter Key`) have nothing to do with converting new lines to HTML's `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Take a look at [nl2br on php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480) which seems exactly what you're looking for. Basically, it's:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return '';
    }
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

**EDIT:**
your example using `nl2br()` may be changed like this:

```
$('#TextArea').keypress(function(evt){
        $('#TextArea1').html(nl2br($('#TextArea').val()));
    });
```

(note that this updates `#TextArea1` on every keypress and doesn't change the value of `#TextArea` wich is what I think you're looking for, but I might be misunderstanding)

**EDIT2:**
If you want to get the behaviour of your old function (with inserting `<br/>`s to `#TextArea`) do this:

```
$('#TextArea').keypress(function(evt){
        $('#TextArea').html(nl2br($('#TextArea').val())); // replace linebreaks first
        $('#TextArea1').html($('#TextArea').val()); // copy to #TextArea1
    });
```

Comment: Does it work on keypress/keup/keydown?

Comment: depends on how you use it - it may be useful if you show more of your code so i could give a hint on how to integrate this.

Comment: I do this by keypress/keup/keydown, It think this is what it does, now can I echo this as nlb2r()?

Comment: Can you look back into the question in a minute, updating it with keypress

Comment: already done, take a look at my edit on how i would change your code.

Comment: So this does not show <BR> in the textarea?

Comment: It has to add a <br> into textarea, but thats okay.  I was looking for one without the <br> though.  Something that is achievable with the PHP nl2br().  Do not want the users to see the <BR> in textarea

Comment: We could also use split/join instead of preg_replace. `str = str.split(/\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n/).join('<br>');`

Answer (score 27):

Here is a function [nl2br](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480) in php.js.

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Philip Peterson
  // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
  // +   improved by: Atli Þór
  // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   improved by: Maximusya
  // *     example 1: nl2br('Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld');
  // *     returns 1: 'Kevin<br />\nvan<br />\nZonneveld'
  // *     example 2: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", false);
  // *     returns 2: '<br>\nOne<br>\nTwo<br>\n<br>\nThree<br>\n'
  // *     example 3: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", true);
  // *     returns 3: '<br />\nOne<br />\nTwo<br />\n<br />\nThree<br />\n'
  var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br ' + '/>' : '<br>'; // Adjust comment to avoid issue on phpjs.org display

  return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

Comment: Does it work on keypress/keup/keydown?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the keyperss. You can use it in your keypress event callback function.