# What's the easiest way to replace '\n' with '<br>'?

Tags: php, javascript, newline

I found some answers in the questions, but I didn't understand and AJAX was used in those solutions.

Now I want to find an easy solution to replace "Enter Key" or \n with `<br>` to find new lines, in JavaScript or PHP.

For a text input(visitors comments) in a `<form>`.

Is there any way to use `string.search()` and don't using AJAX or Jquery or some harder solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nl2br() equivalent in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP's built in function [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) does this.

Answer (score 2):

[nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is the simplest

```
<?php echo nl2br($_POST['someTextArea']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use nl2br in PHP to change new lines to break tags. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most reliable way to do this is using PHP's built in nl2br() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

However, it looks like you would like to achieve this using javascript. That can be done using this:

```
value.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
```