# Jquery/Javascript: Replace html content with html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am a jquery learner ,

My table

```
<table id="table">
<tr >
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>column 3</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>test data</td>
        <td class="address">My compnay, \n New Hil \n
            six singama \n India
        </td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>test data</td>
         <td class="address">New Branch, \n New Hil \n
            six singama \n India
        </td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>test data</td>
         <td class="address">Some company, \n New arcade \n
            six singama \n India
        </td>
        <td>some data</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Second column of each row has a address which contain \n character in it, i want to replace `\n` with `<br>`  tag on loading the page (when document is ready)

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/1/)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   var columns = $('tr').find('td:eq(2  )')
  });
```

Comment: Why can't you just get rid of the `\n` in the source?

Comment: i am getting data in that format from remote server

Comment: Check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        var t = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
        var tx = $(t).text();
        tx = tx.replace(/\\n/g,'<br/>');
        $(t).html(tx);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/12/)

You can also try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:contains(\n)").each(function(){        
        var t = $(this).text();        
        t = t.replace(/\\n/g,'<br/>');
        $(this).html(t);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/V85Vx/13/)

Comment: Everyobody else removed their answer :)