# Copy a textarea value into a div keeping line breaks and html as text

Tags: jquery

I am working on trying to get a way for whatever is in a textarea to move over to a div on a button click. Some of the key features that i am looking for is that i want linebreaks to stay and that if a user inputs any kind of html tags, it will cross over shown the same way.

So something like this that is entered:

```
<body>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <p>more text</p>
</body>
```

will still look the same in the div area.

I have tried a couple of things, but most recently I have tried this:

```
var value = $('#selector-input textarea').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
$('#selector-canvas #canvas').text(value);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Sorry, had full intentions to do so. I guess i jumped the gun to get my question out there. One second..

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan - This does not seem to work for me though. using that code does not leave the HTML as visible it just shows how it would be rendered on the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to preserve the tags you have to replace the angle brackets first, followed by replacing the newline characters - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/2Kg9F/

```
var value = $('textarea').val()
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
    .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

Comment: Working like charm for me, after 7 days finally i got the right answer to my problem ^_^