# Copying Form to Outlook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, outlook

I have created a form which gets copied to outlooks body to send email.
I just completed the form and now i noticed that not all the contents in my form are getting copied to my outlooks body.My form has over 100 lines. So I was wondering if its the size that is causing this issue. Below is my code to send email -

```
 $('.btnSendEmail').click(function (event) {
        var email = 'example@email.com';
        var subject = 'Creation Checklist';
        var emailBody = $('#holdtext').val();
        window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + emailBody;
      });
```

My initial forms code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024750/text-to-outlook-body/40025168?noredirect=1#comment67333380_40025168)

Comment: I do not know if i can post here again. Sorry If this is wrong. How do i edit the font size in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the email parameters through URL which has a limit of 2000 characters, you should use Ajax or server side code to post the form values and redirect to the other page, or just post to it directly.

Comment: I do not know Ajax.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, Ajax should not be any difficult, you just use $.ajax('URL',data), or you can just remove the button click handler and include your input controls in a `<form>` tag and make the form post to the other page that has code for the send email

Comment: Could you please provide the Ajax code for the same. Thanks

Comment: I have already mentioned it in my previous comment `$.ajax('your URL',function(data){//this function will be called when the call is successful })`