# Angular.js strips out line breaks from textarea field text

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular.js 1.6. I noticed that any \n in textarea input field text is being removed before storing into the database. Is there a simple way to turn this behavior off?

Comment: have you tried using pre instead of textarea?

Comment: AngularJS doesn't do that. If it really happens, it's in your code. My guess is that they are still there, but that you're displaying it in HTML, where \n is just treated as white space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nl2br() equivalent in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).