# Simple formatting in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a blog type of website. I got to a point where you can enter text into a textarea box and then click submit to have it appear below. However, I have come to a problem where it does not save the format of the input (notably for me, transforms paragraphs into spaces). I have read that this would require a rich-text editor, and I have tried TinyMCE but it gives a lot more options than needed or which would be able to be used in my case. Is there a simple way to fix this problem? If not, what is the best way to go about this? 
I am mainly after the paragraph, tab, and multiple spaces formatting, everything else is currently not needed. 
Here is what I currently have that is related: 
HTML

```
<!-- Blog Section -->
        <div class="itemBlog">
            <h2 id="itemBlogTitle">My Blog</h2>
            <textarea type="text" rows="10" cols="100" class="blogTextArea" id="blogInput"></textarea>
            <div onclick="newBlog()" class="addBtn">Add</div>
            <ul id="blogList"></ul>
        </div>
        <script src="itemblog.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
// Create a new blog item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newBlog() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("blogInput").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    if (inputValue != '') {
        document.getElementById("blogList").appendChild(li);
    }
    document.getElementById("blogInput").value = "";

    var textarea = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    textarea.className = "close";
    textarea.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(textarea);

    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function () {
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: white-space: pre-wrap; fixed it, thank you

Comment: Just use `white-space: pre-wrap` CSS to preserve whitespace.

Comment: textareas don't contain textNodes. you have to use `.value` to set or get text and not `.appendChild`. also.. you don't need to scream at document.createElement.. it's not deaf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple, just save into your database the input content with id **description**, after that it will respect the paragraph and spaces.

> JQUERY

```js
$('#test').keyup(function() {
  var text = $(this).val();
  var description = text.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/[\n]/g, '<br>');
  $('#text').html(description)
  $('#description').val(description)
});
```

```html
<textarea  id="test" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input id="description" name="description" hidden>
<div id="text"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> js

```js
function formatString(el) {
  var str = el.value;
  str = str.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/[\n]/g, '<br>');
  
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = str;
  document.getElementById('description').value = str;
  
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="formatString(this)" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input id="description" name="description" hidden>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function `nl2br()` as folows:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
        return '';
    }
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467840/nl2br-equivalent-in-javascript)