# How to select text from a multiline textbox with the line breaks in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<textarea style="height: 300px;"  class="jqueryFindBody" cols="20" rows="2">
1
2
3
</textarea>
```

In the asp.net textbox above, if I replace its text with its own text, the line breaks get lost

```
 $('.jqueryFindBody').text($('.jqueryFindBody').text());
```

I tried using html instead of text, but the line breaks are always lost. How do I preserve the line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `.val()`? http://api.jquery.com/val

```
$('.jqueryFindBody').val($('.jqueryFindBody').val());
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tXnaj/

## Update

If you want to display the value of the `textarea` element in HTML then you'll need to parse the endline characters into `<br />` tags. You can do this with a simple RegExp:

```
$('.jqueryFindBody').val().replace(/\r|\n/g, '<br />');
```

This finds all the `\n` and `\r` characters and replaces then with `<br />` tags.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tXnaj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Newlines in text boxes are represented as \n and \r (newline and carriage return)
The topic is also discussed here: [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)