# Double line breaks with 'pre' tag and 'nl2br'

Tags: php, html, line-breaks, pre, nl2br

I used `nl2br` function for `pre` tags, but I've encountered a strange problem: there are 2 line breaks but there's only one `<br />` tag.

For example:

```
code in line 1<br />
code in line 2<br />
```

Displays as:

```
code in line 1

code in line 2
```

instead of:

```
code in line 1
code in line 2
```

Comment: `nl2br` will insert `<br />` for each `\r` *and* for each `\n` if there's any character at all between them. Show your input string.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping text in a `<pre>` tag will force it to be displayed as written: including spaces, tabs and new lines.
Therefore the carriage return will create a new line AND the `<br />` will create a second new line.

Comment: true, but how we can remove new lines before we send it to browser?

Comment: Does this need to be encapsulated in a `<pre>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace ("/\n+/", "", $pre)` or even better `preg_replace ("/[\n\r]+/", "", $pre)`

Comment: @Vahid - try `preg_replace_all("/<br\b.*?>/", "", $text)`

Comment: thanks for reply, but it just remove br not invisible line break, in output there is just one br tag but browser render tow line break!

Comment: @Vahid - there should be no `<br \>` tags inside of `<pre> ... </pre>`

Comment: my means was without `preg_replace_all("/<br\b.*?>/", "", $text)` there is one br tag and i just need to remove invisible line break, not br, removing br tag case missing line break problem, when user make copy and past, in some browser like chrome safari and...

Comment: @Vahid - you should consider to update your question, to make it clear, show us more input/output and code you have, otherwise this is just waist of time, sorry........

Comment: ya i think so but i can't explain it more, i think it's a strange problem, maybe i must try more about solution, i must check all things. thanks.

Comment: problem solved with your guide, but i replaced `\r\n` insted of `\n\r`  and invisible lines disappeared! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to apply nl2br() when you're writing it inside a pre block.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The correct answer is much simpler. Don't use nl2br with pre.

nl2br  adds `<br />` to text for html, but the pre tag already preserves the text format.
That's what it means. `<pre>` = preformatted.

Yes, something like this will work, until it doesn't.

```
<pre>
    preg_replace ("/[\n\r]+/", "",nl2br(file_get_contents("/crashbody.txt")))
</pre>
```

But that's silly. You're adding line breaks and removing them. To preserve your whitespace and your line breaks, let `<pre>` do it's job.

```
<pre>
    file_get_contents("/crashbody.txt")
</pre>
```

Or better still:

```
<div style = "white-space: pre; text-align:left;">
    file_get_contents("/crashbody.txt")
</div>
```