# jQuery - Import text, recognize line breaks

Tags: jquery, ajax

Forgive my newbieness...
Referencing this posit: [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

how do I marry

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';    
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}
```

or

```
textAreaContent=textAreaContent.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

into my existing function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "Notes_copy.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#NotesTxtBx").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

what is my textAreaContent in the above example for instance

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "Notes_copy.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#NotesTxtBx").html(data.replace(/\\n/g,"<br>"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I actually expanded it to $("#NotesTxtBx").html(data.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g,"<br>")); to actually catch the line breaks in the txt file