# show text in multi line in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

ihave problem in jquery when send request to div.

so i have variable like this :-

```
$text = "hi  ";
```

so this variable in php i called like this way:-

```
nl2br($text);
```

to display in multi line, i need same function to show text like php.

Comment: Did you try search functionality of this site? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent

Answer (score -1):

```
$(selector).html(text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
```