# is there a trick in html to achieve the same as php-command nl2br?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I refer here to the simple command with:

`<p style="text-align: center;font-size:12pt;">text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-text-as-abc-</p>`

Is there a trick to use nl2br (is a command in php) for the text-as-sampling-text
in order to auto-format in a given box or in a given window where abc-text is
placed within this box or window.

It is to much work to place `<br>` manually into the text-as-sampling-news ...

... or is auto-formating until edge of window/box already working without problems in
every browser with `<p style="text-align: center;font-size:12pt;">text</p>` without any

 tag ?!

... do I need a special workout of nl2br for files in *.css ?

This questions look trivial - but I want to avoid incompatibilities with displaying
text universally in all browsers.

Comment: It depends on your CSS and HTML markup. Do you need the line breaks in specific spots or are you just trying to wrap the paragraph of text? Either way, include your HTML and CSS so we can see what we're working with here...

Comment: This sounds like a possible XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: is this what you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2919337/1113766

Comment: hi, ... You can look non-perfect homepage at http://nosy-x.com - there in first box from up to down in center (container) - the news are not text-formatted correctly. Want to know, if I should simply leave out <br> in <p style=...>text-as-abc-text-as-abc<br>text-as-abc-text-as-abc</p> ... would this work universally as auto-format in all browsers then ?! Or do I need to shovel more code in it (globally or locally) for index.html only ?! thx.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - see new comment ... this is (not finish) what I tried.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking or what you expect to happen. "Format" is a general word -- format how? Likewise, auto-format just means formatting programmatically. You need to be specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - sorry, sometimes it is tricky to transport the German thought into the right English ... somebody told me now, that in command-tag of html <p style= ...>text-text-text</p> the text between the tags is in modus auto-format in given space (window or box) - I mean auto-format with that lines are breaking automatically and continue to next line one step deeper in screen. So normally I dont need to use <br> then - only if I want to force a break in the line. So I wanted to know if this "auto-format" of line-breaking (within <p style...></p>) is universal through all browsers...

Comment: - this thread is then apparently solved, but have to test it thoroughly this week out.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about what you're looking for because there's no *new line* within your paragraph, but in CSS [`white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) implements sort of `nl2br()` effect:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/voqin/1/edit)**.

It's worth noting that `pre-line` value [is supported in **IE8+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Browser_compatibility).

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)**:

> `pre-line`
>   Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at
>   newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.