# Replace new lines to <br>, without start of string,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm trying to replace new lines in java script to `<br>`'s. But...

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(\n|\r)/gm, "<br>"));
```

and the others function like this one replaced first line too. So I'm getting formatted text with enters at the start. Example

```
<br> (?)
<br> (?)
Text
<br>
```

How to solve this issue  ?

```
$(".class").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\\n/g, "<br/>"));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"<br/>")`? What does _So I'm getting formatted text with to enters at the start._ mean?

Comment: With br's at the start, in database I dont have it

Comment: I guess this comment should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2919363/2328888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove the leading '\n' from the string, like this:

```
$(".class").each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).text().trim('\n').replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") );
});
```