# Losing line break when displaying text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I can see the line breaks "↵" for a string in Chrome Developer Tools

```
<br>↵↵<br>Event Status: confirmed↵<br>Event Description: Hog Day (Night )and Hog Day (Day)↵↵Friday...
```

If i double click this and paste to Notepad, the line breaks are preserved.

When i save the string to an object like so,

```
var summary = el.find("summary").text();
var volunteerEvent = {title: title, summary: summary}
```

and eventually display it on a page,

```
$('#volunteerEventDescription').empty().html(event.summary);
```

the line breaks are gone and it's a huge chunk of text.

How do i keep the newlines?

Comment: Tried `$('#volunteerEventDescription').empty().text(event.summary);` ?

Comment: Yes i did and it didn't work. I also tried replace('\n';,"") but it doesn't seem to select them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two obvious options. Which one is the right one for you depends on how much control over the formatting you want.

1. Use the `pre` tag and the new lines will be respected. `pre` is for preformatted text and will use non-proportional font so it may not render as you would wish. See [pre on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) for more details.
2. Replace the new lines with the `br` tag. You can do this with a regular expression: `stringValue.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')`. A more robust regular expression is present on another question: [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent).

As an update in 2023, another option is to use the CSS `white-space` pretty with `pre`, `pre-wrap` or `pre-line` as the value. See [MDN white-space page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The `nl2br` function equivalent from PHP can be found in php.js: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/. `nl2br`, as the name might subtly suggest, converts newlines to break tags.