# Convert \n line breaks to HTML <BR> line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple idea to convert my `\n` line breaks from my ajax JSON call to `<br>` so that it would properly display my data.

I tried many different ways to perform the conversion but I keep getting an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.replace is not a function
```

The issue seems to be the way I'm making this call:

```
var incident = incident.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

From what I see on the forums here this is how we're suppose to use `.replace` but I'm not understading why it doesn't like it.

I tried doing this as well:

```
"<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Impact.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")+"</td>"+
```

This works but if the field is empty it returns with an error stating that it cannot read `.replace` of undefined. Would anyone have any ideas?

Full code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, incident) {
        var incident = incident.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

        $('body').append(

          "<table border='1' width='800' >"+
          "<tr  bgcolor='#9aff99' align='center'>"+
          "<td width='800px' colspan='4'><strong>Transfert de connaissances</strong></td>"+
          "</tr>" +
          "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
          "<td width='165'>Billet:</td>"+
          "<td>"+incident.Incident+"</td>"+
          "<td width='165'>Priorité:</td>"+
          "<td>"+incident.PrioritéValue+"</td>"+
          "</tr>"+
          "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
          "<td width='165'>Description:</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Description+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td colspan='4' width='800px' bgcolor='#9aff99' align='center'>Détails</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td width='165'>Impact:</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Impact+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td width='165'>Dépannage</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Dépanage+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td colspan='4' width='800px' bgcolor='#9aff99' align='center'>Suivi</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td width='165'>Prochain Suivi:</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Suivi+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td width='165'>Ressource:</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.Ressources+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr bgcolor='#fff'>"+
           "<td width='165'>Prime:</td>"+
           "<td colspan='3'>"+incident.ResponsableValue+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "</table>"+
           "<br><br>");

        })

    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

Comment: You need to replace each field separately. You can't replace everything in the entire object at once. Even better, use a `td { white-space: pre-wrap; }` rule in the CSS so you don't even need <br> tags.

Comment: test value to make sure it is defined and is string before using `replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a string method on an object, not on property values within that object.

There is no `Object.replace()` so that will throw error

Similarly `undefined.replace()` will also cause error

Presumably you only have to fix a few property values but first it is necessary to make sure those values are defined and are strings before using `replace()`

Try

```
function convertBreak(str){
   if(!str){
     return ''; // don't want `undefined` printing into page
   }
   // if it's something other than string, return it as is
   if( typeof str !=== 'string'){
      return str;
   }else{
     return str.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
    }
}

incident.Description = convertBreak(incident.Description);
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your code is here:

```
    var incident = incident.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

You are redeclaring the variable incident. Try to remove the redeclaration:

```
    incident = incident.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: It isn't a redeclaration ... the variable is being declared locally in a function closure