# White space textarea in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that has a form. In the form I have a textarea field. When this is filled and displayed in the manner below

eg . this is how it was written in the textarea box

```
The manager,

Abc limited,

private bag,

earth.
```

It displayed like this

```
The manager, Abc limited, private bag, earth.
```

how can I make it stay the way it was written

Comment: Show us relevant codes so that we can help you better

Comment: please provide your code so we can help you out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `innerText` attribute of the element that will hold the textarea value.

**Important:**  At the backend side, you have to preserve the `\n` in the Database or whatever it's being used to store the data to get it back and render the content exactly as was saved.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

div.innerText = textarea.value;
textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  div.innerText = this.value;
});
```

```html
<h3>Enter text and press enter</h3>
<small>The entered text will appear automatically</small>
<p>
<textarea>
The manager,

Abc limited,

private bag,

earth.</textarea>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think you have some DRY issues :p

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to recreate your error was by misspelling `<textarea>` as `<text area>`. When the space is added, the error occurs. When properly spelled line breaks are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

HTML ignores new lines/whitespace unless you style the element with `white-space:pre` like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/j2xLL658/)

Comment: I have tried using `.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');`. Only works when assigning value to `InerHTML` element in Javascript.  But not works for `fetch` value to backend. The special character code will returns. (`&#60;br /&#62;>`). So your approach works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `\n` for line breaks inside `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php, then you can echo echo nl2br($textarea);

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

or for jquery

[jQuery convert line breaks to br (nl2br equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919337/jquery-convert-line-breaks-to-br-nl2br-equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not really giving us a lot to go on how you print the text field. But my guess is that if you use php you should wrap your variable in a nl2br() function.

Get more information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php